# Adding undo redo feature to the FingerPaint application ( one of the google's sample application )

Tags: android, path, canvas, undo-redo

I want to modify FingerPaint application and add undo and redo features to it. It basically draws Path's to the canvas at onDraw method and draws same paths to a bitmap too. Anyway my first thought was to save bitmaps as files but there might be some more efficient way . I am waiting for suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new canvas, push it onto a stack, set it to the same `width` and `height`, and then use [`drawImage()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Canvas_tutorial/Using_images) with the main canvas as the first image to copy the contents over. To undo, walk down the stack and use `drawImage()` in reverse. (Don't pop off the stack, or you won't be able to redo.)

Comment: Nice idea but do you have any Example ?

Comment: @iDroidExplorer No, I don't have one pre-made. Which part of it are you not able to do?

Comment: Actually i am doing this type of paint: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9748206/android-how-to-do-this-framing-paint       But now got stuck with the undo/redo functionlity. I dont able to do that. So need help in that case.