# Android: How to do this framing paint?

Tags: android, android-canvas, draw, flood-fill

I Have Some static images like below:

[image]

Now, I want is, when i touch on the face or hand, then the selected color should be fill on that skin portion.

See below image of result:

[image]

So how to get the result like above ??
Redo and Undo Functionality Should be also there.

I have try with the FloodFill color but doing that i can only able to do color in to the perticular portion. as FloodFill only fill the color till the same pixwl color comes. If the touch place pixel color get change the it will not fill color on it.

So Usinf FloodFill i got the result like below image, If i press on the hand, then only hand portion will fill with color, instead of it i want to fill color to the other hand and face also.
[image]

So Please help me in this case.

**EDITED**

After some reply i got the solution like [this one](http://pastebin.com/KTH2Lgt9).

But still there is a memory issue. It consume lots of memory to draw the color. So please can anyone help me for it ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can have a complete image colored the actual way and when you fill a certain region with a color, it will replace all the regions that is specified by that color to be filled in.

Layman's terms:

1. User will click on the hand of the OUTLINE
2. That click location will be checked with another image with perfectly color coded regions. Lets call it a MASK for this case. All the skin regions will have the same color. The shirt areas will be another color.
3. Wherever the user clicks, the selected color by the user will be applied to every pixel that has that similar color in the MASK, but instead of painting directly on the MASK, you paint onto the pixels of the the OUTLINE.

I hope this helps.

Feel free to comment if you want an example and then I can update the answer with that, but I think you can get it from here.

EDIT:

Basically start off with a simple image like this. This we can call as **OUTLINE**

[image: Simple image]

Then as the developer, you have to do some work. Here, you color code the **OUTLINE**. The result we call a **MASK**. To make this we, color code the regions with the same color that you want. This can be done on paint or whatever. I used Photoshop to be cool lol :D.

[image: Mask]

Then there is the **ALGORITHM** to get it working on the phone. Before you read the code, look at this variable.

```
int ANTILAISING_TOLERANCE = 70; //Larger better coloring, reduced sensing
```

If you zoom up on the image specifically noting the black regions of the border, you can actually see that sometimes, the computer blends the colors a little bit. In order to account for that change, we use this tolerance value.

**COLORINGANDROIDACTIVITY.JAVA**

```
package mk.coloring;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Bitmap.Config;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;

public class ColoringAndroidActivity extends Activity implements OnTouchListener{
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    findViewById(R.id.imageView1).setOnTouchListener(this);
}

int ANTILAISING_TOLERANCE = 70;
public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
    Bitmap mask = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.mask);
    int selectedColor = mask.getPixel((int)arg1.getX(),(int)arg1.getY());           
    int sG = (selectedColor & 0x0000FF00) >> 8;
    int sR = (selectedColor & 0x00FF0000) >> 16;
    int sB = (selectedColor & 0x000000FF);

    Bitmap original = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.empty);       
    Bitmap colored = Bitmap.createBitmap(mask.getWidth(), mask.getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas cv = new Canvas(colored);
    cv.drawBitmap(original, 0,0, null);

    for(int x = 0; x<mask.getWidth();x++){
        for(int y = 0; y<mask.getHeight();y++){
            int g = (mask.getPixel(x,y) & 0x0000FF00) >> 8;
            int r = (mask.getPixel(x,y) & 0x00FF0000) >> 16;
            int b = (mask.getPixel(x,y) & 0x000000FF);
            if(Math.abs(sR - r) < ANTILAISING_TOLERANCE && Math.abs(sG - g) < ANTILAISING_TOLERANCE && Math.abs(sB - b) < ANTILAISING_TOLERANCE)
                colored.setPixel(x, y, (colored.getPixel(x, y) & 0xFF000000) | 0x00458414);
        }
    }
    ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1)).setImageBitmap(colored);

    return true;
}
```

}

This code doesn't provide the user with much of color choices. Instead, if the user touches a region, it will look at the **MASK** and paint the **OUTLINE** accordingly. But, you can make really interesting and interactive.

**RESULT**

*When I touched the man's hair, it not only colored the hair, but colored his shirt and hand with the same color. Compare it with the **MASK** to get a good idea of what happened.*

[image: Result]

This is just a basic idea. I have created multiple Bitmaps but there is not really a need for that. I had used it for testing purposes and takes up unnecessary memory. And you don't need to recreate the mask on every click, etc.

I hope this helps you :D

Good luck

Answer (score 4):

Use a FloodFill Algorithm. [Fill the complete canvas but keep the bound fill area as it is like circle, rectangle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8723590/fill-the-complete-canvas-but-keep-the-bound-fill-area-as-it-is-like-circle-rect/12777805#12777805). You can also check this link. [Android: How to fill color to the specific part of the Image only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9629299/android-how-to-fill-color-to-the-specific-part-of-the-image-only/12794381#12794381). The general idea get the x and y co-ordinates on click.

```
 final Point p1 = new Point(); 
 p1.x=(int) x; p1.y=(int) y; X and y are co-ordinates when user clicks on the screen
 final int sourceColor= mBitmap.getPixel((int)x,(int) y);
 final int targetColor =mPaint.getColor();
 new TheTask(mDrawingManager.mDrawingUtilities.mBitmap, p1, sourceColor, targetColor).execute(); //Use AsyncTask and do floodfillin the doinBackground().
```

Check the above links for floodfill algorithmin android. This should help you achieve what you want. [Android FingerPaint Undo/Redo implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10165965/android-fingerpaint-undo-redo-implementation). This should help you modify according to your needs regarding undo and redo.

Edit:

A post on stackoverflow led me to a efficient way of using flood fill algorithm without delay and OOM.

Picking from the SO Post

Filling a small closed area works fine with the above flood fill algorithm. However for large area the algorithm works slow and consumes lot of memory. Recently i came across a post which uses QueueLinear Flood Fill which is way faster that the above.

Source :

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16405/Queue-Linear-Flood-Fill-A-Fast-Flood-Fill-Algorith

Code :

```
public class QueueLinearFloodFiller {

    protected Bitmap image = null;
    protected int[] tolerance = new int[] { 0, 0, 0 };
    protected int width = 0;
    protected int height = 0;
    protected int[] pixels = null;
    protected int fillColor = 0;
    protected int[] startColor = new int[] { 0, 0, 0 };
    protected boolean[] pixelsChecked;
    protected Queue<FloodFillRange> ranges;

    // Construct using an image and a copy will be made to fill into,
    // Construct with BufferedImage and flood fill will write directly to
    // provided BufferedImage
    public QueueLinearFloodFiller(Bitmap img) {
        copyImage(img);
    }

    public QueueLinearFloodFiller(Bitmap img, int targetColor, int newColor) {
        useImage(img);

        setFillColor(newColor);
        setTargetColor(targetColor);
    }

    public void setTargetColor(int targetColor) {
        startColor[0] = Color.red(targetColor);
        startColor[1] = Color.green(targetColor);
        startColor[2] = Color.blue(targetColor);
    }

    public int getFillColor() {
        return fillColor;
    }

    public void setFillColor(int value) {
        fillColor = value;
    }

    public int[] getTolerance() {
        return tolerance;
    }

    public void setTolerance(int[] value) {
        tolerance = value;
    }

    public void setTolerance(int value) {
        tolerance = new int[] { value, value, value };
    }

    public Bitmap getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void copyImage(Bitmap img) {
        // Copy data from provided Image to a BufferedImage to write flood fill
        // to, use getImage to retrieve
        // cache data in member variables to decrease overhead of property calls
        width = img.getWidth();
        height = img.getHeight();

        image = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(image);
        canvas.drawBitmap(img, 0, 0, null);

        pixels = new int[width * height];

        image.getPixels(pixels, 0, width, 1, 1, width - 1, height - 1);
    }

    public void useImage(Bitmap img) {
        // Use a pre-existing provided BufferedImage and write directly to it
        // cache data in member variables to decrease overhead of property calls
        width = img.getWidth();
        height = img.getHeight();
        image = img;

        pixels = new int[width * height];

        image.getPixels(pixels, 0, width, 1, 1, width - 1, height - 1);
    }

    protected void prepare() {
        // Called before starting flood-fill
        pixelsChecked = new boolean[pixels.length];
        ranges = new LinkedList<FloodFillRange>();
    }

    // Fills the specified point on the bitmap with the currently selected fill
    // color.
    // int x, int y: The starting coords for the fill
    public void floodFill(int x, int y) {
        // Setup
        prepare();

        if (startColor[0] == 0) {
            // ***Get starting color.
            int startPixel = pixels[(width * y) + x];
            startColor[0] = (startPixel >> 16) & 0xff;
            startColor[1] = (startPixel >> 8) & 0xff;
            startColor[2] = startPixel & 0xff;
        }

        // ***Do first call to floodfill.
        LinearFill(x, y);

        // ***Call floodfill routine while floodfill ranges still exist on the
        // queue
        FloodFillRange range;

        while (ranges.size() > 0) {
            // **Get Next Range Off the Queue
            range = ranges.remove();

            // **Check Above and Below Each Pixel in the Floodfill Range
            int downPxIdx = (width * (range.Y + 1)) + range.startX;
            int upPxIdx = (width * (range.Y - 1)) + range.startX;
            int upY = range.Y - 1;// so we can pass the y coord by ref
            int downY = range.Y + 1;

            for (int i = range.startX; i <= range.endX; i++) {
                // *Start Fill Upwards
                // if we're not above the top of the bitmap and the pixel above
                // this one is within the color tolerance
                if (range.Y > 0 && (!pixelsChecked[upPxIdx])
                        && CheckPixel(upPxIdx))
                    LinearFill(i, upY);

                // *Start Fill Downwards
                // if we're not below the bottom of the bitmap and the pixel
                // below this one is within the color tolerance
                if (range.Y < (height - 1) && (!pixelsChecked[downPxIdx])
                        && CheckPixel(downPxIdx))
                    LinearFill(i, downY);

                downPxIdx++;
                upPxIdx++;
            }
        }

        image.setPixels(pixels, 0, width, 1, 1, width - 1, height - 1);
    }

    // Finds the furthermost left and right boundaries of the fill area
    // on a given y coordinate, starting from a given x coordinate, filling as
    // it goes.
    // Adds the resulting horizontal range to the queue of floodfill ranges,
    // to be processed in the main loop.

    // int x, int y: The starting coords
    protected void LinearFill(int x, int y) {
        // ***Find Left Edge of Color Area
        int lFillLoc = x; // the location to check/fill on the left
        int pxIdx = (width * y) + x;

        while (true) {
            // **fill with the color
            pixels[pxIdx] = fillColor;

            // **indicate that this pixel has already been checked and filled
            pixelsChecked[pxIdx] = true;

            // **de-increment
            lFillLoc--; // de-increment counter
            pxIdx--; // de-increment pixel index

            // **exit loop if we're at edge of bitmap or color area
            if (lFillLoc < 0 || (pixelsChecked[pxIdx]) || !CheckPixel(pxIdx)) {
                break;
            }
        }

        lFillLoc++;

        // ***Find Right Edge of Color Area
        int rFillLoc = x; // the location to check/fill on the left

        pxIdx = (width * y) + x;

        while (true) {
            // **fill with the color
            pixels[pxIdx] = fillColor;

            // **indicate that this pixel has already been checked and filled
            pixelsChecked[pxIdx] = true;

            // **increment
            rFillLoc++; // increment counter
            pxIdx++; // increment pixel index

            // **exit loop if we're at edge of bitmap or color area
            if (rFillLoc >= width || pixelsChecked[pxIdx] || !CheckPixel(pxIdx)) {
                break;
            }
        }

        rFillLoc--;

        // add range to queue
        FloodFillRange r = new FloodFillRange(lFillLoc, rFillLoc, y);

        ranges.offer(r);
    }

    // Sees if a pixel is within the color tolerance range.
    protected boolean CheckPixel(int px) {
        int red = (pixels[px] >>> 16) & 0xff;
        int green = (pixels[px] >>> 8) & 0xff;
        int blue = pixels[px] & 0xff;

        return (red >= (startColor[0] - tolerance[0])
                && red <= (startColor[0] + tolerance[0])
                && green >= (startColor[1] - tolerance[1])
                && green <= (startColor[1] + tolerance[1])
                && blue >= (startColor[2] - tolerance[2]) && blue <= (startColor[2] + tolerance[2]));
    }

    // Represents a linear range to be filled and branched from.
    protected class FloodFillRange {
        public int startX;
        public int endX;
        public int Y;

        public FloodFillRange(int startX, int endX, int y) {
            this.startX = startX;
            this.endX = endX;
            this.Y = y;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One basic way would be something like the [floodfill algorythm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill).
The Wikipedia article describes the algorythm and its variations pretty well.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8070401/android-flood-fill-algorithm) you can find a implementation on SO. But depending on your specific needs this one has to be modified.