# Flood fill algorithm on vector drawable image view

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-vectordrawable, flood-fill, android-graphics

I want to create application like this.

[Flood fill algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9748206/4535930)

I applied that code and it is working fine with JPG or PNG file.
But I want to use that algorithm with Vector drawable imageview

Vector drawable imageview before flood fill
[image]

After flood fill of vector imageview
[image]

Expected result should be like this (Flood fill work perfectly when I set JPG or PNG file)
[image]

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_flood_fill);

    iv_FloodFillActivity_image = findViewById(R.id.iv_FloodFillActivity_image);
    iv_FloodFillActivity_image.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                floodColor(event.getX(), event.getY());
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
}

private void floodColor(float x, float y) {
    final Point p1 = new Point();
    p1.x = (int) x;// X and y are co - ordinates when user clicks on the screen
    p1.y = (int) y;

    Bitmap bitmap = getBitmapFromVectorDrawable(iv_FloodFillActivity_image.getDrawable());
    //bitmap = bitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);

    int pixel = bitmap.getPixel((int) x, (int) y);
    int[] sourceColorRGB = new int[]{
            Color.red(pixel),
            Color.green(pixel),
            Color.blue(pixel)
    };

    final int targetColor = Color.parseColor("#FF2200");

    QueueLinearFloodFiller queueLinearFloodFiller = new QueueLinearFloodFiller(bitmap, sourceColor, targetColor);

    int toleranceHex = Color.parseColor("#545454");
    int[] toleranceRGB = new int[]{
            Color.red(toleranceHex),
            Color.green(toleranceHex),
            Color.blue(toleranceHex)
    };
    queueLinearFloodFiller.setTolerance(toleranceRGB);
    queueLinearFloodFiller.setFillColor(targetColor);
    queueLinearFloodFiller.setTargetColor(sourceColorRGB);
    queueLinearFloodFiller.floodFill(p1.x, p1.y);

    bitmap = queueLinearFloodFiller.getImage();
    iv_FloodFillActivity_image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
}

private Bitmap getBitmapFromVectorDrawable(Drawable drawable) {
    try {
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), drawable.getIntrinsicHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        drawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
        drawable.draw(canvas);
        return bitmap;
    } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Check Class : [QueueLinearFloodFiller](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12913103/4535930)

How can I use vector drawable?

Comment: android supports vector drawables `<ImageView
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  app:srcCompat="@drawable/name" />`

Comment: Not working, the result is same. I edit the question please check.

Comment: show me your code

Comment: @Eminem Please check edited question

Comment: Use jpg image, instead of png

Comment: @BhaveshButani got any solution?